# MODULE_NOT_FOUND ERROR WHEN SEND AN EMAIL

Tags: typescript, mailgun, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Good evening guys, i'am trying to send an email by with an request, using AdonisJS and mailgun but when, i sende in my insomnia evertyhing works fine, with status 200, but in my terminal an error appears and the email is not sent the error

```
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\mail\\build\\src\\Drivers\\Ses.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\mail\\build\\src\\Mail\\MailManager.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\mail\\build\\providers\\MailProvider.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@poppinss\\utils\\build\\src\\esmRequire.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@poppinss\\utils\\build\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\require-ts\\build\\src\\Compiler\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\require-ts\\build\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\assembler\\build\\src\\requireHook\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\labrantes\\www\\prisma-backend\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\assembler\\build\\register.js',
    'internal/preload'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you install `@adonisjs/mail` package (command : `npm i @adonisjs/mail
`)? and execute `node ace configure @adonisjs/mail`?

Comment: yes i have made it